# jQuery $.each loop

Tags: jquery, json, facebook-graph-api

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=cinema&type=post";
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               dataType: "jsonp",
               success: function(msg){
                 console.log( msg );
                 $.each( msg.data , function(obj){
                    $('#cinemas').append(obj.message);
                 });
               }
             });
        });
    </script>
```

Yet nothing is displayed, can anyone spot anything obviously wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: does `console.log(msg)` output anything to the console?

Comment: Yes, there is definitely data being returned

Comment: maybe try this: append(document.createTextNode(obj.message));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.each` needs `(index, value)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=cinema&type=post";
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       dataType: "jsonp",
       success: function(msg){
         $.each( msg.data , function(i, obj){
                $('#cinemas').append(obj.message);
         });
       }
     });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/q8b7Q/1/

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong argument in `$.each`.

```
  // Use the 2nd argument---------v
 $.each( msg.data , function( i, obj ){
    $('#cinemas').append(obj.message);
 });
```

Comment: This is correct. The object, by the way, can be obtained via the implicit `$(this)` variable... so you could have 

`function(){
    $('#cinemas').append($(this).message);
 });`

Comment: @Java: You do not need to wrap `this` in `$()`, as it is not a DOM element.  `$('#cinemas').append(this.message);`

Comment: I don't believe that applies for `JQuery.each()` but it does apply to `.each()` since the latter extends off `JQuery.fn` and would return the DOM node to which it is assigned.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: `$.each()` behaves the same in that `this` will be a reference to the value of the current item in the iteration. It's `$.map()` that changes it.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: `this` works fine in `$.each`.  It just is set to whatever the object is.

Comment: I was replying to @Java regarding `$(this)`

Comment: `this` will work fine, but as usual, if you want to object to be jQuery-fied, `$(this)` is better, b/c then you can do all the fun stuff. The basic point remains correct, `this` holds the object at the current iteration, thanks for the clarification guys

Comment: @Java: Yes, but most of jQuery's methods are intended to work on DOM elements, so it wouldn't make sense to jQuery-fy `this` (or `obj`) in this case. The `$(this).message` code you posted won't work because a jQuery object doesn't have a `.message` property. You'll be appending `undefined`.

Comment: @patrick: Aah yep, totally see that, somehow just missed that... Yes you are absolutely right, `this` is the way to go here, since we are dealing with a plain js object. Good call

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need to add `callback=?` for 'JSONP' to work correctly.</strike>

```
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=cinema&type=post&callback=?";
```

EDIT: In `$.each` the callback is `function(index, value)`, so you need to use the 2nd param.

```
$.each( msg.data , function(i, obj){
  $('#cinemas').append(obj.message);
});
```

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Ah, it seems that jQuery adds the `callback=?` for you.

Comment: It does automatically if you set `dataType: "jsonp"`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
         var g = 0;
            $.each(msg, function(key, value) {
             $('#cinemas').append(msg["data"][g]["message"]);

            g++;
        });
```